# "DateTime Invalid Locale Format" SoapFormatter.Serialize

Tags: c#

If there are any ways for solve this error.
Here Is my details as shown below :

```
public string GetSerializedString<T>(T objT)
{
    SoapFormatter objSoapFormatter = new SoapFormatter();
    objSoapFormatter.Serialize(objMemoryStream, objT);
}
```

I am getting following error once I'm passed class object of ABC[]

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'DateTimeInvalidLocalFormat' has detected a problem in ".."
>
> Additional information: A UTC DateTime is being converted to text in a format that is only correct for local times. This can happen when calling DateTime.ToString using the 'z' format specifier, which will include a local time zone offset in the output. In that case, either use the 'Z' format specifier, which designates a UTC time, or use the 'o' format string, which is the recommended way to persist a DateTime in text. This can also occur when passing a DateTime to be serialized by XmlConvert or DataSet. If using XmlConvert.ToString, pass in XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind to serialize correctly. If using DataSet, set the DateTimeMode on the DataColumn object to DataSetDateTime.Utc.

Comment: tell us more about how `GetSerializedString` is used to serialize a `DateTime`? I am confused by the `ABC[]`, what is it? Show the definition for the `ABC` type.

Comment: [Serializable] ABC{ public DateTime Field1 { get; set; }}

Comment: I made one common function "GetSerializedString" which is return me as serialized string of object which I passed.

Comment: I think there is problem in date field of ABC class. But I can't change anything in ABC class. Because its come as an argument so I am not allowed to change anything. Please help me if any solution.